# How to repair door frame from animal damage

Tags: repair, trim, door-frame

Previous owners had a cat or some other devil beast. How do I repair this?

Pretty sure I should just buy new moulding... but how do I repair the actual frame? Sand-able wood putty or filler? Any recommendations?[image]

Comment: Maybe I cant tell what is wrong with the frame from this picture.  It seems like damage is 9g% on the molding on the edge.  If you replace that with a new piece and repaint that might be enough.   If it were my house I would just repaint it.  Old house character.   If some one asked I would mutter something about the "devil cat".

Comment: @Willk the majority of the damage is on the casing, but there’s a little bit in the jamb too. I’m looking for product type recommendations to fill and sand. Woodfill? Putty? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the moulding and get a little wood filler to fill the other scratches the paint. This isn't that bad.

Jonathan

Comment: This is not a proper answer. **EXPLAIN HOW to do what you are advising to do**. What is the proper method to use wood filler in this situation.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer